# Load another page in the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was able to display a dialog when clicking on a link. How do I the pull another page's contents while in the dialog?

Answer (score 4):

I've done this in the past by loading the 'other content' into a div and then displaying that div as a dialog.

```
$('#dialog').load('other_content.html', function(){ 
    $(this).dialog();
}
```

jQuery Docs for [Ajax/load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather not pre-load other content, it will most likely delay the page load time.

Comment: Jon - I've given you +1 because your answer is right and the OPs response made me laugh!

Answer (score 1):

Is the jQuery [load()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) method what you are looking for?

Comment: I am not sure how to get a reference on the dialog window to make it load different content without closing and reopening.

Comment: Try something like $('#theDialog').load('someOtherFile.html');  Then when you click the link, it will have the contents of the remote file.  There are various ways of loading the file, but this is the most straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a file via jquery's i.e. load-method, then it it is possible 
to load further content from the loaded file when it is dropped into the window dialog:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myDropZone").load("another-file.html");
});
</script>
```

This code has to be returned from the loaded html content.

BTM, you can load content in different ways, but be aware of what you are doing. Do not load files recursively.
Would be the same as a loop.

Hope this helps

Comment: Should the above function reside in the html of the original page or dialog? I dont't understand which page responds to events inside the dialog, is it the dialog itself, or the page that invokes it?

Comment: Sorry, if I had not written clearly. I do  mean the page, which is being invoked by your first request (not the dialog).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Scripts/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var UIDialogId = 0;

            $('.UIDialogOpen').live('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(this.href);
                UIDialogId++;

                $('<div/>', {
                    'id': $(this).attr('data-dialog-id') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-id') : 'UIDialog' + UIDialogId,
                    'class': 'UIDialog'
                }).appendTo('body').dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr('data-dialog-title') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-title') : 'Message',
                    position: ['center', 'center'],
                    modal: true, resizable: false, zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                    minWidth: $(this).attr('data-dialog-minwidth') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-minwidth') : '300px',
                    minHeight: $(this).attr('data-dialog-minheight') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-minheight') : '300px',
                    maxWidth: $(this).attr('data-dialog-maxwidth') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-maxwidth') : '300px',
                    maxHeight: $(this).attr('data-dialog-maxheight') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-maxheight') : '300px',
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                })
                .load(this.href);

                //Or   //Use .load(this.href); and comment or delete below append line.

                //.append('<h1>Hi.. This is Testing </h1> <input type="button" class="UIDialogCancel" value="Cancel" /> <input type="button" class="UIDialogClose" value="Close" />');


                $('.UIDialogClose, .UIDialogCancel').live('click', function (e) {
                    var obj = $(this)
                    e.preventDefault();
                    obj.parents('.UIDialog').dialog('close');
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="your url" title="test1" class="UIDialogOpen">test1</a>
    <br />
    <a href="your url" title="test2" class="UIDialogOpen">test2</a>
    <br />
    <a href="your url" title="test3" class="UIDialogOpen">test3 </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in  <a href="your url" title="test1" class="UIDialogOpen">test1</a> in href u need to put u r url link there. then it will work.