# How to load page in jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, razor

I am trying to load another page in a jQuery dialog. I have already looked to a lot of articles (including the ones below). It seems that the accepted technique is:

```
$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
                var d1= $('#dialog-import').dialog({
                resizeable: false,
                height: 600,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    'My button1': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });

            d1.load('/DataSets/ImportSpreadsheet/91D55CAC-6C2C-46EE-8730-0DBFE26D1D92').dialog('open'); 

        });
    });
```

That opens the dialog, including the complete content and my two dialog buttons, however, the two dialog buttons do not work (I cannot click on them).

Other alternatives of the code, like:

```
 $('#dialog-import').load('/DataSets/ImportSpreadsheet/' + a, function () {
                $('#dialog-import').dialog('open');
            });
```

Result in this error in the Google Developer Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'
```

I must be missing something dumb. However, I have really been looking it over, without any luck.

Thanks.

This is what I am trying to do, tried their advise with no luck:

[jQuery Modal dialog onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989174/jquery-modal-dialog-onclick)

[dialog in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428896/dialog-in-jquery)

[how to load a page with jquery ui dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608249/how-to-load-a-page-with-jquery-ui-dialog)

[Load another page in the dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761467/load-another-page-in-the-dialog)

[Jquery dialog to open another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756283/jquery-dialog-to-open-another-page)

Comment: I think you forgot to include the jQueryUI code since the `dialog` method is unknown.

Comment: It is included. Please note that the dialog opens if I don't call the load (if I do $('#dialog-import').dialog('open') it opens, but it doesn't have any content as I didn't load anything).

Comment: I can only reproduce the error with an invalid URI in the `.load()` call, which does not seem to line up with your description since you _are_ receiving the asynchronous data. You might find a better error (if any) by replacing the `.load()` call with the full [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead, since the success/error functions are explicit. I believe the problem might be related to a bad response from the `.load()` which breaks the dialog's functionality.

Comment: Andy, I had also tried the $.get() one and it behaves the same. The Url that I am loading contains a complete html page, ie: it is not a subsection. Is that valid?

Comment: It should not cause a problem if the HTML is complete and not just a fragment. The browser's `.innerHTML` often filters elements like `<html>`, `<head>` and `<title>` anyway. How about using the full [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to do the load instead and also make sure `dataType: 'html'` is set in the options. jQuery's data type guessing is not always correct in my experience. Without a working example I can't offer anything more concrete, but happy to keep guessing :-)

Comment: I understand. I appreciate the comments and will keep trying. I'll post the solution if I ever find it. Thanks.

Comment: Andy (or anyone else out there), I am testing returning a subset HTML (without header, etc), from the Chrome Console it works. Now I need to change my web app to return that to see if it really works. I'll post back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20204/discussion-between-rufo-and-andyb)

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the issue was that I was trying to load a complete page that included the header, body, html elements. jQuery didn't like that.

I found two possible solutions:

1. Use an C# MVC partial view. Make sure that the partial view doesn't include header, html, etc., elements. Using that the code in the original question works without issues.
2. Use an iFrame element, and load the page that you are looking for changing the src attribute, like in the code below.

   $('#selector').click(function () {
                   $('#dialog-import').attr('src','/DataSets/ImportSpreadsheet/...'); 
                   $('#dialog-import').dialog('open');
                  });

Still, I am puzzled by so many people saying that they do not have to worry about the header/body tags, like this posting implicitly says: [ASP.NET Mvc jquery ui dialog as view or partialview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363749/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ui-dialog-as-view-or-partialview)

I will continue to research, but somebody having my same issue could find this useful.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you got a solution and that you added an answer as it will be very useful to others searching in the future. Did you try the `$.ajax()` method in the end? I'm sure I've loaded a full HTML in a dialog before and had to specify `dataType: 'html'` in the options. A partial view would always be preferable anyway since there is no unnecessary data being sent but I'm still interested in why it was not working with the full page.

Comment: No. I haven't tested the $.ajax yet. I tested the $.get. I will test the ajax when I have a time (putting fires off). Thanks.