# jquery ui dialog error on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jquery 2.1.4 and UI 1.11.4.
I load a dialog with :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 750,
            height: 450,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
                },
            hide: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
                },
            buttons: {
            "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close"); /* fires an error */
            }
            }
        });

        $(".bookingcancel").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("option", "title", "Gestion de votre planning").dialog("open");
            $("#dialog-form").load(this.href);
        });
    });
```

I have links with IDs (ie: loda-data.php?id=1 / loda-data.php?id=2 ...)
When I click, the dialog opens fine, the page loads within the dialog window.

When I click on the top-right "close" cross, it closes (no error).
When I click on the "Cancel" button, the dialog won't close, and I get an error :
    TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    $(this).dialog("close");

I found many topics here and there, but nothing that works...

I also have a problem when I open then close the dialog : it won't open a second time when clicking another link.

Any clue ? Thank you.

EDIT : this is the code of the dialog I use to open, then load data, then need to close, then need to open again with  another data
     < div id="dialog-form" title="" >< /div >

Comment: After some research, it seems that .load() inside a dialog can break the functionality. Namely if it is loading an entire page with headers and especially if it loads jQuery a second time. Can you ensure that is not happening? ref - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13596594/4987197

Comment: Hello ! I saw that you are french speaker. I upload your code in jsfiddle and it seems working fine. Check it out with your browser and tu pourras m'en dire plus ! https://jsfiddle.net/odLyq5d8/

Answer (score 1):

When loading a page using `.load()` into a dialog, ensure a few things:

#1: Make sure the page you are loading does not have `<html></html>` tags present. The duplicate tags will cause issues in your DOM

#2: Make sure the page you are loading does not have duplicate references to libraries. Examples: jQuery, jQueryUI, bootstrap, etc. The duplicate references to external files can also cause many issues.

Comment: Same error with your piece of code, or with the array.

Comment: @user3801953 You're going to have to set up a sandbox recreation of this issue then. I think you have other issues happening at this point. jQuery is not broken, and this syntax is correct

Comment: that's why I can't understand... seems to be a good piece of code, I have no other script running, and I also put my code on a separate page, with no PHP session on it = same problem...

Comment: Thanks for all the replies and help. The page I load has a simple form. I have < style> *** < /style> on top of the page.. I had already found that a page could contain some html code, but not that you *SHOULD NOT* just use < html> /* my form */ </html> !!! I just took off the opening and closin tag, and it  ***** works fine ! thanks guys...

Comment: @user3801953 I figured it was something like that. Glad you got it worked out. I will edit my answer accordingly so that it reflects the actual solution